# Symfony 5 doctrine_migrations error on script boot

Tags: symfony, symfony5

As far as i can tell, i can't see any other questions that ask this, so here goes:

I've been running the latest Symfony, for a side project, and encountered this error as i was writing the app. Nothing i do now fixes it, not even re-installing symfony, and i have no idea what the problem even is. I am getting the error:

> The parameter "doctrine_migrations.dir_name" has a dependency on a
>   non-existent parameter "kernel.root_dir". Did you mean one of these:
>   "kernel.project_dir", "kernel.cache_dir", "kernel.logs_dir"?

[image: error encountered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to document the root cause.

Symfony 5 removed `kernel.root_dir` parameters. Doctrine Migrations Bundle uses it as default value for `dir_name`.

It's been discussed. See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/305 and  https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/pull/295.

SOLUTION: right now (Symfony 5 and Migrations bundle 2.1.x), you should not delete `doctrine_migrations.yaml`. Leave it there with a `dir_name` that does not raise en error.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using the undefined `kernel.root_dir` variable in your `config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml` config file.

You should replace it by `kernel.project_dir`:

```
# config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#configuration

Comment: i don't have a doctrine_migrations.yaml config, and after changing one of the vendor files, im getting a different error, `Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\ServerLoadRepository": argument "$registry" of method "__construct()" references interface "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?`

Comment: at this point i am assuming it is a symfony bug, so i will close this question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

at this point i am assuming it is a symfony bug, so i will close this question. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
composer remove orm
composer require symfony/orm-pack
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a very brief description of what it does so other people don't have to read through the question, reverse engineer your code or look up the language documentation to get an idea of what problem your answer is solving or how it works. That's the expectation on this site. You're new and can correct it so I'll let it slide but it wound up on the low-quality posts review queue because it has no explanation at all.